# How to resolve this crash issues using Embedded Service SDK Chat version 4.1.0

Tags: mobile, servicecloud, snap-ins

We keep on received this crash issues as below, we believe this regarding the okhttp3 library issues used by the embedded service sdk. Anyone have idea to resolve this issues?

> Blockquote
>   Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: value for name x-liveagent-session-key == null
>          at okhttp3.Headers.checkValue(Headers.java:268)
>          at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add(Headers.java:312)
>          at okhttp3.Request$Builder.addHeader(Request.java:196)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.http.okhttp.SalesforceOkHttpRequest$Builder.addHeader(SalesforceOkHttpRequest.java:127)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentlogging.internal.request.BatchedEvents.build(BatchedEvents.java:114)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentClient.createRequest(LiveAgentClient.java:239)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentClient.sendUsingHttpClient(LiveAgentClient.java:220)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentClient.send(LiveAgentClient.java:135)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.LiveAgentSession.onRequestPending(LiveAgentSession.java:186)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.integrity.LiveAgentQueue.attemptToSend(LiveAgentQueue.java:157)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.integrity.LiveAgentQueue.add(LiveAgentQueue.java:132)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentlogging.internal.InternalLiveAgentLoggingSession.flush(InternalLiveAgentLoggingSession.java:166)
>          at com.salesforce.android.chat.core.internal.logging.LiveAgentChatLogger.onConnected(LiveAgentChatLogger.java:331)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentlogging.internal.InternalLiveAgentLoggingSession.onConnected(InternalLiveAgentLoggingSession.java:242)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentlogging.internal.PodConnectionManager.notifyOnConnected(PodConnectionManager.java:229)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentlogging.internal.PodConnectionManager.onSessionCreated(PodConnectionManager.java:190)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.SessionListenerNotifier.onSessionCreated(SessionListenerNotifier.java:62)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.handler.CreateSessionHandler.handleResult(CreateSessionHandler.java:111)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.liveagentclient.handler.CreateSessionHandler.handleResult(CreateSessionHandler.java:49)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.utilities.control.BasicAsync.setResult(BasicAsync.java:288)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.utilities.threading.JobQueue$JobAsync.access$001(JobQueue.java:156)
>          at com.salesforce.android.service.common.utilities.threading.JobQueue$JobAsync$1.run(JobQueue.java:170)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:238)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6006)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:937)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:798)
>   Blockquote